# Eclipse IDE weird blinking space

Tags: eclipse, terminal, format, ide

Does anyone know how to get rid of this thing?

[there is this cursor in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSUQK.png)

It acts weird with backspacing and removes whole line or doesn't remove and returns to the beginning of line.

I tried restarting eclipse and terminal it didn't help

Usually it single blinking space here it's double space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD1kW.png

Tried restarting eclipse, terminal. Didn't help

Comment: You are in the overwrite mode, showing by a cursor as a blinking box instead of a blinking `|`. Hit the `Insert` key to end overwrite mode.

Comment: It did change the mode in the editor but the screenshots  are for the terminal. And it didn't help for the terminal :(

Comment: Try a simple text editor, if you see the same then @howlger is right and he's speaking about the keyboard key, not an editor setting,